# Renderscrip issue

Tags: android, renderscript

I have a very long renderscript code (about 2000 lines). It is taking along time to process it when trying to run the application (i left it overnight and it took 195 min 6 sec)..

Also when I tried to run it, I get this error:

```
 07-13 09:50:12.924  16359-16374/? E/Icing: Not enough disk space. Will not index.
07-13 09:50:13.142  16465-16480/com.jeanius.renderscript E/bcinfo: Error: input file is not a bitcode file.
07-13 09:50:13.142  16465-16480/com.jeanius.renderscript E/RenderScript: Bitcode is not in proper container format (raw or wrapper)
07-13 09:50:13.197  16465-16465/com.jeanius.renderscript E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jeanius.renderscript/com.jeanius.renderscript.RenderscriptOptimization}: android.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Loading of ScriptC script failed.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: android.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Loading of ScriptC script failed.
        at android.renderscript.ScriptC.<init>(ScriptC.java:60)
        at com.jeanius.renderscript.ScriptC_cobylaSolver.<init>(ScriptC_cobylaSolver.java:41)
        at com.jeanius.renderscript.RenderscriptOptimization.onCreate(RenderscriptOptimization.java:45)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
        ... 11 more
07-13 09:50:23.275  16518-16598/? E/fb4a(:<default>):MmsConfig: MmsConfig.loadMmsSettings mms_config.xml missing uaProfUrl setting
07-13 09:50:26.869  16625-16737/? E/Icing: Not enough disk space. Will not index.
07-13 09:50:28.142  16625-16737/? E/Icing: Aborting indexing of corpus FC3392E516647AE98EF58CDB1B4F72A158619C1F
07-13 09:50:28.877  16625-16737/? E/Icing: Aborting indexing of corpus FC3392E516647AE98EF58CDB1B4F72A158619C1F
07-13 09:57:55.147  17193-17212/? E/fb4a(:<default>):MmsConfig: MmsConfig.loadMmsSettings mms_config.xml missing uaProfUrl setting
```

Anybody can help please?

Comment: Can you post your .rs source file? I asked for it on the code.google.com bug as well, but maybe you check SO more often.